# How do I access the parts of twig.html arrays that start with a #?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to make an html.twig file and change how a paragraph renders its content, but I can't access the part of the array that has the info I need.

This is the vardumper line I used to get this far

```
{{ vardumper(content["field_recommended_content"][0]["#node"]) }}
```

and this is the result I get from that

```
Node {#2249 ▼
  +in_preview: null
  #values: array:28 [▶]
  #fields: []
  #fieldDefinitions: array:30 [▶]
  #languages: array:3 [▶]
  #langcodeKey: "langcode"
  #defaultLangcodeKey: "default_langcode"
  #activeLangcode: "x-default"
  #defaultLangcode: "en"
  #translations: array:1 [▶]
  #translationInitialize: false
  #newRevision: false
  #isDefaultRevision: "1"
  #entityKeys: array:4 [▶]
  #translatableEntityKeys: array:8 [▶]
  #validated: false
  #validationRequired: false
  #loadedRevisionId: "1111"
  #revisionTranslationAffectedKey: "revision_translation_affected"
  #enforceRevisionTranslationAffected: []
  #entityTypeId: "node"
  #enforceIsNew: null
  #typedData: EntityAdapter {#2251 ▶}
  #cacheContexts: []
  #cacheTags: []
  #cacheMaxAge: -1
  #_serviceIds: []
  #_entityStorages: []
  #isSyncing: false
}
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out how to access the contents of the #node array, if I try to do

```
{{ vardumper(content["field_recommended_content"][0]["#node"]["#values"]) }}
```

it returns null, and if I try to do

```
{{ vardumper(content["field_recommended_content"][0]["#node"][#values]) }}
```

it crashes the page.

Does anyone know how to access those array values that start with # and don't already have "" around them?

Comment: "Change how the paragraph renders its content" - I would advise leveraging display modes and field formatters with their respective twig templates for this.

Comment: @Kevin so targeting the fields specifically instead of the paragraph as a whole?

Comment: Paragraphs can have display modes configured too.

Comment: @Kevin if the recommended content field that I am trying to access is an entity reference can I still do what I need to do with a display mode? (I am trying to add accessibility arias to the links in the entity reference field)

Comment: The general rule to follow when coding templates is if something is hard to do in twig, do it in a preprocess hook instead, where you have the full power of php available.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong is there a page that shows examples and documentation on how to combine the two? I haven't done much work at all with the preprocess and twig side of Drupal 8 before so I am a little lost